# Keeping Secrets in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

Suppose I have a secret which I keep in a type

```
data Secret a = Secret a deriving Functor, Show
sec :: Secret String
```

and I want to allow computation on the secret, and some way to view results e.g.

```
getSecretHash :: Show a => Secret a -> String
```

or

```
askQuestion :: (a->Bool) -> Secret a -> Bool
```

but I don't want to allow the secret to be directly extracted (I know you could bruteforce one of the above ways, but assume the secret is large so this is unfeasible).

Of course someone could just write

```
reveal :: Secret a -> a
reveal (Secret x) = x
```

and I know I can prevent this by putting secret in a module and not exporting the constructor but instead giving a `makeSecret :: a->Secret a`, but I want to know if there's a way to do it using the type system.

**Without hiding the constructor, how can I make a type that can't have its value arbitrarily extracted?**

Comment: Why do you not want to use the hiding-the-constructor method?

Comment: This can be done with some fancy crypto by never storing the `a` in the first place, but in all the approaches I know of you must significantly restrict what computation can be done (e.g. by deciding on a fixed set of operations). See e.g. fully homomorphic encryption and multi-party computation as starting points for discussion.

Comment: Do you need to be able to *combine* secret values with each other?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't need to be able to combine values. My model for this is programs on devices that may need to use identifying data but mustn't be allowed to send it over the network, e.g. it's ok to display the IMEI on the screen, but transmitting it (with `tx:: Transmittable a=> a->IO()`) is forbidden.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I'm interested in how the type system might be applied here and in the broader sense of how computations can obliged to be independent. But in some sense it shouldn't matter, I'm not asking if it's the right thing to do or not.

Comment: Keep in mind that, if the secret has N bits of information, using N `askQuestion` calls we can retrieve it, hence it can be recovered in linear time. But I guess you want "hiding" in the programming languages sense, rather than in the cryptography sense.

Comment: @chi that's a good point, and I tried to cover it. I suppose you could mitigate it by trying to keep track of how many bits you've leaked and cap it but that would probably require dependent types and might be better left to the next project.

Comment: I can't say anything about this particular library, but I had remembered seeing something along these lines before. Using a security monad of sorts to ensure data is never leaked. Take a look: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/seclib

Answer (score 7):

This

> askQuestion :: (a -> Bool) -> Secret a -> Bool

looks a bit like a flipped version of [`runCont`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:runCont)

```
λ import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont
λ :t runCont
runCont :: forall r a. Cont r a -> (a -> r) -> r
λ :set -XTypeApplications
λ :t runCont @Bool
runCont @Bool :: forall a. Cont Bool a -> (a -> Bool) -> Bool
λ :t flip (runCont @Bool)
flip (runCont @Bool) :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> Cont Bool a -> Bool
```

So perhaps in that respect your `Secret` type is `Cont Bool`, and you can create values with [cont](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:cont):

```
 cont :: forall a. ((a -> Bool) -> Bool) -> Cont Bool a

 makeSecret :: forall a. a -> Cont Bool a
 makeSecret a = cont $ \f -> f a
```

The actual value is hidden behind a function.

Comment: I suppose there are some types `a` for which you can reconstruct the `a` using this representation, though. (`a ~ Bool` would be an obvious example.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson isn't this unavoidable if we want to be able to view the results of computations eventually?

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson Perhaps some form of linear types could be used to forbid "too many queries"? Or perhaps `Secret` values could only be created and queried inside a `ST`-like environment which tracked the number of accesses and could throw errors at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

> Without hiding the constructor, how can I make a type that can't have its value arbitrarily extracted?

No. Hiding the constructor is precisely the right tool for that, and the only reasonable method I can think of.

Comment: Existential types can do it too.

Comment: @dfeuer Sounds like you should compose an answer!

Comment: @dfeuer I'd also like to see an answer with existential types

Answer (score 5):

Well, if using fancy Haskell types isn't a requirement, then you can use the old function closure trick.  Just define the data type as the query function:

```
data Secret a = Secret { query :: (a -> Bool) -> Bool }
```

Exporting a helper function to construct secrets may be helpful (though it's entirely optional, as the constructor is public and anyone can make their own `makeSecret` function):

```
makeSecret :: a -> Secret a
makeSecret x = Secret (\f -> f x)   -- or Secret ($x) if you're feeling clever
```

The definition of `askQuestion` is straightforward:

```
askQuestion :: (a -> Bool) -> Secret a -> Bool
askQuestion = flip query
```

I guess this is ultimately similar to `danidiaz`'s answer, but the monad machinery isn't really necessary just to store a secret in a function.

Note that, if you need a functor instance for this `Secret`, Haskell has no problem deriving one, and it works as expected:

```
> askQuestion (=="Stack Overflow") $ fmap (++" Overflow") $ makeSecret "Stack"
True
```

I guess technically you can get it back out by cheating, like so, but I'm not sure that any of the other methods can avoid this:

```
> askQuestion (\x -> unsafePerformIO (putStrLn (show x) 
     >> return False)) $ makeSecret "secret"
"secret"
False
>
```

Comment: Cool answer! As for your final comment, is it true that you still can't obtain the raw value inside the secret in the code (unless you write it to a file and read it or similar)?

Comment: You wouldn't have to store it in a file, you could store it in an `IORef`

Comment: I like this answer quite a lot, but it seems impossible to gauge the value without more context wrt the question and situation.  For example, if you give me a `Secret ByteString` in this construction I can certainly use unsafe calls to write the secret out to a file (among other things).